# MATLAB / Octave : Increment array with an array of indexes

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, octave

I am struggling to optimize a piece of code.
I will have to deal with many numbers (millions) and my code is running slow.
Let's suppose that we have the matrix 3x3:

```
A = [ 8 1 6; 3 5 7; 4 9 2 ];
```

I want to know how many elements are in the intervals [0, 3), [3, 6) and [6, 9). Therefor, i need a matrix 1x3 :

```
p = [ 2 3 4 ];
```

My code is :

```
p = zeros(1, 3);
for i = 1 : 9
   p( floor(A / 3) + 1 ) += 1;
```

I want to do it without for loops, but the code :

```
p = zeros(1, 3);
p( floor(A / 3) + 1 ) += 1;
```

Outputs :

```
p = 1 1 1
```

Any ideas why? And how can i correct this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are implementing is a histogram:

```
p=histc(A(:),[0,3,6,9]); %For MATLAB 2014b or newer use histcounts instead
```

It returns `p=[2,3,3,1]` because it implicitly creates an interval [9,inf)

To explain the indexing problem. Multiple assignments to the same index are not supported in MATLAB. They always take the last assignment:

```
x=zeros(3,1)
x([1,1,2,1])=[1,2,3,4] %results in x(1)=4
```

And for the increment operator, the same rules apply. It behaves like:

```
x([1,1,1,1])=x([1,1,1,1])+1
```

For the general case of such an multi-assignment, you can use accumarray:

```
%assume you want x([1,1,2,1])=[1,2,3,4]
accumarray([1,1,1,1].',[1,2,3,4].')
%results in [7,3]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Histogram bin counts**

As Daniel writes in his answer, you're computing counts of values in histogram bins. An alternative method to `hist` is using the newer [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) command (recommended for newer Matlab versions).

```
A = [ 8 1 6; 3 5 7; 4 9 2 ];
[p, ~, ~] = histcounts(A, 0:3:9);

%// p = 2     3     4
```

---

**Matrix relation operators followed by non-zero element count**

You could also make use of matrix relational operators followed by [`nnz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nnz.html) command to count non-zero elements:

```
A = [ 8 1 6; 3 5 7; 4 9 2 ];
p = [nnz(A < 3);
    nnz(A >= 3 & A < 6);
    nnz(A >= 6)];         %// alternatively nnz(A >= 6 & A < 9) for the last entry

%// ...

p =

     2
     3
     4
```

---

**"Quickest?"**

From some quick `tic`/`toc` tests, it seems that—on my system (running Matlab R2014b)—the latter `nnz` method is:

- ~3-4 times quicker than the `histcounts` method.
- ~5-6 times quicker than the histogram method using the older `hist` command.

I have not tried, however, to see how this scales as `A` becomes larger, in case this is the case for your application.